# Bayesian inference for dependent data

Tags: statistical-inference

Is it possible to use bayesian inference technique for data which does not follow the memoryless property? What is the likelihood function and prior in this case?

Comment: Questions about statistical inference might be better suited at stats.stackexchange.com. In its current form this question seems too borad - more information is certainly needed. (The prior and likelihood surely depend on what you are trying to model, what data you have etc.)